# Menu items shown in Navigation menu?

Tags: 7, theming, routes, navigation

I made a module for displaying nodes(links) from database. And I have simple question, why are the links displayed in the navigation menu? I want to be displayed in a separate menu (like navigation menu with my custom title etc etc...), but whatever I do they show up in the navigation menu.

[image]

```
function test_menu(){

$items = array(); 

  $items['test1'] = array(
    'title callback'   => 'test_callback1',
    'page callback'    => 'test_output1',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

      $items['test2'] = array(
    'title callback'   => 'test_callback2',
    'page callback'    => 'test_output2',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,

  );
       ..... etc etc
      return $items;
}
```

This is page-test.tpl.php

```
<?php
 print $content;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using the `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM` type, which will add the item to a menu, and haven't set a `menu_name`. From [the docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7):

> "menu_name": Optional. Set this to a custom menu if you don't want your item to be placed in Navigation.

If you want to add the link to a different menu try something like this:

```
$items['test1'] = array(
  'title callback'   => 'test_callback1',
  'page callback'    => 'test_output1',
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  'menu_name' => 'main-menu'
);
```

If you don't want the link to be added to a menu automatically at all, change `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM` to [`MENU_CALLBACK`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/constant/MENU_CALLBACK/7).

Remember to clear the caches when you make any change to `hook_menu()`, otherwise the changes won't be picked up.

Comment: I understand, main-menu works, change links destination, and now I need to create custom menu with hook_install or so? Tnx for reply.

Comment: Yes you can create a menu in hook_install (or maybe hook_enable if that suits better), or you can just create it through the UI as normal